# Is there a better way to write this

Tags: sql

I have this query below. But i think there is a better way of writing this. The only difference between the two is the VacancyType check

```
IF @VacancyType = '' 
        SELECT COUNT(a.[ApplicationID]) [AppCount], YEAR(a.[DateCreated]) [Year], MONTH(a.[DateCreated]) [Month]
        FROM [Application] a
        INNER JOIN [Vacancy] v ON v.VacancyID = a.VacancyID
        INNER JOIN Staff s ON s.StaffID = v.StaffID

        WHERE 
        v.[DateCreated] >= @DateFrom AND v.[DateCreated] <= @DateTo 
        AND (@OfficeID = 0 Or s.OfficeID = @OfficeID)
        AND v.VacancyType IN (SELECT TypeID FROM VacancyType) 

        GROUP BY YEAR(a.[DateCreated]), MONTH(a.[DateCreated])
        ORDER BY YEAR(a.[DateCreated]), MONTH(a.[DateCreated])

    ELSE 
        SELECT COUNT(a.[ApplicationID]) [AppCount], YEAR(a.[DateCreated]) [Year], MONTH(a.[DateCreated]) [Month]
        FROM [Application] a
        INNER JOIN [Vacancy] v ON v.VacancyID = a.VacancyID
        INNER JOIN Staff s ON s.StaffID = v.StaffID

        WHERE 
        v.[DateCreated] >= @DateFrom AND v.[DateCreated] <= @DateTo 
        AND (@OfficeID = 0 Or s.OfficeID = @OfficeID)
        AND v.VacancyType = @VacancyType

        GROUP BY YEAR(a.[DateCreated]), MONTH(a.[DateCreated])
        ORDER BY YEAR(a.[DateCreated]), MONTH(a.[DateCreated])
```

Comment: Try [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: That is non-standard SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT COUNT(a.[ApplicationID]) [AppCount], YEAR(a.[DateCreated]) [Year], MONTH(a.[DateCreated]) [Month]
FROM [Application] a
INNER JOIN [Vacancy] v ON v.VacancyID = a.VacancyID
INNER JOIN Staff s ON s.StaffID = v.StaffID

WHERE 
v.[DateCreated] >= @DateFrom AND v.[DateCreated] <= @DateTo 
AND (@OfficeID = 0 Or s.OfficeID = @OfficeID)
AND ((@VacancyType = '' AND v.VacancyType IN (SELECT TypeID FROM VacancyType)) 
  OR (v.VacancyType = @VacancyType)
)

GROUP BY YEAR(a.[DateCreated]), MONTH(a.[DateCreated])
ORDER BY YEAR(a.[DateCreated]), MONTH(a.[DateCreated])
```

Comment: I believe this is not equivalent to the original code since the `v.VacancyType = @VacancyType` is evaluated even when the `@VacancyType = ''` is true.

Comment: When you have a row in the table where `VacancyType = ''` then such row is in the result even if '' value is not in the `VacancyType` and you have `@VacancyType = ''`

Comment: @RadimBača What are you talking about? This answer is similar to your except `@VacancyType <> ''`. But you do not need this condition, it is like `ELSE`. But your case is like 2 `IF` operators. Please check. You can use http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the only difference is in `v.VacancyType` condition, then you can use `OR`

```
    SELECT COUNT(a.[ApplicationID]) [AppCount], YEAR(a.[DateCreated]) [Year], MONTH(a.[DateCreated]) [Month]
    FROM [Application] a
    INNER JOIN [Vacancy] v ON v.VacancyID = a.VacancyID
    INNER JOIN Staff s ON s.StaffID = v.StaffID

    WHERE 
    v.[DateCreated] >= @DateFrom AND v.[DateCreated] <= @DateTo 
    AND (@OfficeID = 0 Or s.OfficeID = @OfficeID)
    AND 
    (
       (@VacancyType = '' AND v.VacancyType IN (SELECT TypeID FROM VacancyType)) OR
       (@VacancyType <> '' AND v.VacancyType = @VacancyType)
    )
    GROUP BY YEAR(a.[DateCreated]), MONTH(a.[DateCreated])
    ORDER BY YEAR(a.[DateCreated]), MONTH(a.[DateCreated])
```

Comment: Little note: I'ld add some parenthesis between AND and OR just to make clear in what order the condition is elaborated

Comment: @RobertKock there are parenthesis

Comment: I replied too fast. Before reading your answer very vell. Sorry about that.